# Is there such a Chef service that managed by K8s?

Tags: kubernetes, chef, configuration-management

I'm looking for a way to manage a Chef into my K8s cluster.
My cluster is scaling up and down and I need a way to bootstrap different dependencies for each new node in the namespace.
My nodes are in AWS cloud and I'm aware for the userData but it's not enough and Chef has other purposes and advantages.

The goal is not just having Chef as a pod in K8s but also to have the tools to manipulate different rules over my cluster.

Answer (score 0):

There are already docker images created by community for deploying chef server, also you can create your Chef container via Dockerfile.

Here are some useful links that can help you.

[Approaches to Configuration Management: Chef, Ansible, and Kubernetes](https://kublr.com/blog/approaches-to-configuration-management-chef-ansible-and-kubernetes/)

[Ansible and Chef deployment with Kubernetes in Various cloud services.](https://medium.com/@paraashkamdar/ansible-and-chef-deployment-with-kubernetes-in-various-cloud-services-fdff09101d2e)

Also this one below is from book by PackPub named "Kubernetes Cookbook", it is not free but you can get 10 days free trial and check that also.

[Auto-deploying Kubernetes through Chef recipes](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/virtualization_and_cloud/9781785880063/6/ch06lvl1sec44/auto-deploying-kubernetes-through-chef-recipes)

Hope it helps!